# Phidget interfacekit 8/8/8 outputs

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My phidgets interfacekit 8/8/8 works great with the sensors (inputs). However it also has 8 outputs. Can someone tell me if these can be used as well? I have found an example for the sensors here:

http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/phidgets_ros.html#InterfaceKit_ROS_API
And another package here: http://ros.org/wiki/phidgets
But the documentation is either missing or vague..

However the usage of the outputs is not documented..or am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44173/phidget-interfacekit-8/8/8-outputs/) by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2573 on 2012-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://ros.org/wiki/phidget_ik allows you to use the outputs, although it doesn't provide a ROS API (see http://ros.org/doc/api/phidget_ik/html/classPhidgetIK.html for the class description). Another option would be the stack at https://launchpad.net/phidgets-ros-pkg .

---

Originally posted by [wcaarls](https://answers.ros.org/users/3110/wcaarls/) with karma: 76 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0